# Blender 2.8 viewport shading - random color: how to assign different color

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, visibility

When in the 3D viewport, you can set your mesh colors to "random". But can you change this randomly assigned color of one certain mesh to something different, in case you -like me - happen to have a much too similar color in another mesh, and unfortunately the two are overlapping?

Comment: Perhaps this may help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143444/is-there-a-way-to-reset-the-seed-of-random-material-in-blender-2-8-viewport